# Show CVS annotations by default in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

In Eclipse you can show CVS annotations (which user changed which line in which commit) for a file by choosing Team->Show annotations... from it's context menu. However, I want to enable this for all files in my CVS projects by default. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Short answer: no. Unfortunately not. This is not a preference.

Comment: I've see that come... :( Could you please post that as an answer, so I can mark it as correct if no one else has a solution in the next 24 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no. Unfortunately not. This is not a preference.

Answer (score 6):

Found the same problem in svn in eclipse. To avoid clicking, which is slow, I set a hotkey for show annotations. It is not the full solution but faster than clicking every time, you want to use show annotations function.