# Eclipse: bind Command key to show SVN annotations

Tags: eclipse, svn, keyboard-shortcuts, subclipse, editing

I wanted to show SVN annotations in Eclipse (3.7) automatically. It turns out I can only bind a key (Command) to it:

[Show CVS annotations by default in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171433/show-cvs-annotations-by-default-in-eclipse)

It's under General->Keys. But it's not working. I tried a few combinations of (Command, Binding and When) settings, however the annotations never appeared on the left margin of any editor. From the context-menu (Team->Show Annotation...) it's working fine.

I'm about to use Ctrl+Shift+Z which is not used by any Eclipse or OS command yet.

Can someone share me the exact Command?

Comment: Have you chosen the right category?

Comment: I'm not sure. To the keyword 'Annotation' I receive 12 results, about 10 of these seems related to CVS/SVN. Categories are Views, Navigate, CVS, SVN, Window, Source. I tried a couple of them but the 'When' list looks infinitely a lot and I kind of gave up trying...

Comment: Try with `show an` keyword and chose svn as a category and `In Windows` as when.

Comment: That is WEIRD: I did what you wrote and when I open the context menu's Team->Show Annotation... it's even showing me the Ctrl+Shift+Z key-hint. And it's still not doing it if I press those keys. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to binding the key command you need to activate the SVN command group in your current perspective.

### Step 1: Bind Command

- Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys
- Search for "show annotation" and set a key binding for category "SVN", "Ctrl+Shift+Z" for
  example (I use "Ctrl+Alt+A"). Choose "In Windows" as "When".

### Step 2: Activate SVN Command Group

- Window -> Customize Perspective... -> Command Groups Availability ->
  check "SVN"

Comment: I didn't have a `Command Groups Availability` tab, but I did have a tab called `Action Set Availability` (perhaps different versions of Eclipse had named it differently)